# bootstrap div not aligning with canvas

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4, three.js

I have a canvas inside a div with threeJS, and would like to display the purple bar (which will be for user settings) on the right side of the threejs window. The problem is that for some reason bootstrap is not recognising that I want to put these 2 columns together in a row and is placing them on separate rows. I would expect what I have currently to work, and can't see anything wrong with it... I have a similar situation somewhere else in the project, but with only divs, which is working fine. There is no lay-out scss code other than one thats resetting the margin and padding. there are also no other html files in use for this component.

```js
const threeCanvas = document.getElementById('threejs-canvas') as HTMLCanvasElement;
this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas: threeCanvas });
```

```html
<div class="row" style="background-color: whitesmoke; height: 100px"></div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <canvas id="threejs-canvas">
            <app-threejs [width]=400 [height]=350></app-threejs>
        </canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2" style="background: blueviolet; height: 621px;">test</div>
</div>
```

[image: Situation]

EDIT: Desired result would be something like this:
https://www.elfskot.nl/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/thumbnail-configurator-780x520.png

SOLVED: I had ng-bootstrap installed without bootstrap...

Comment: Are you sure bootstrap css has loaded? Check the network tab if you can see it there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML and class usages is fine, please check if your Bootstrap CSS files are loading and applying to your page.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="row" style="background-color: whitesmoke; height: 100px"></div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/400x350">
    </div>
    <div class="col-2" style="background: blueviolet; height: 621px;">test</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I removed the canvas tag and replaced it with a placeholder image, this so it replicates the space used by this element.

Comment: I have just now tried to add a m-5 class to my top bar, with no visual results. I suspect you might be right.

Comment: Appearantly something went wrong with my installation of ngbootstrap for angular. I have it installed but my angular.json cant find the module...

Comment: I have added the solution to the post, I was assuming ng-bootstrap also installed bootstrap as a dependency. Which it doesnt

Comment: Glad it worked in your favor! If you could accept this answer that would be great!